# Failed to convert property value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.Class[]] for property 'annotatedClasses'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My spring bean data base connection myDataSource is as follows. and i am getting exception 
how can i solve this exception. the RoomUser is in correct location.
i try to change the  tags, but now use.

```
 <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.room.user.beans.RoomUser</value>
            <value>com.room.user.beans.RoomUserType</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.Class[]] for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.room.user.beans.RoomUser]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:716)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:427)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:341)
```

Comment: "the RoomUser is in correct location" - no, it's not, otherwise this error wouldn't be occurring.

Answer (score 3):

There is problem with your model class only. spring is not able to find class RoomUser in your application-context.xml file

```
 <list>
        <value>com.room.user.beans.RoomUser</value>
        <value>com.room.user.beans.RoomUserType</value>
    </list>
```

I was also facing same problem. check whether RoomUser is in correct package ?

Comment: same package only

Answer (score 0):

Similiar concept with the answer above.
Use `mvn clean` to clear the target directory, and run the application again so that the ApplicationContext can be reloaded.